# Send parameter to action method

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

At the moment I have this code:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Add", "Review", "Review"))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Review</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TEKST)
        </div>
         <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.TEKST)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

This will send me to: localhost:4470/Review/Add?Length=6
The thing that I actually want is this url: localhost:4470/Review/Add?tekst=sdfsdf

How can I modify this code that it will use "tekst" as parameter instead of length? And as value the content of the textbox.

UPDATE:
This are my action methods:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    return View();
}

public ActionResult Add(string tekst)
{
    ViewBag.test = tekst;
    return View();
}
```

In the View page of Create, I would like to have a form, with a textbox or textarea, that sends an action to Add, the content of the textbox or textarea should be in parameter "tekst" of action method "Add"

SOLUTION:
See the post of CD Smith

Comment: could you be more clear??please

Comment: This code is currently in Create.cshtml and will be called from controller: Review, action: Create. Here I want to have an input called "tekst" and send that parameter to controller review, action: Add(string tekst){ here the logic for adding txt to db, that is already working}. With this code it sends parameter Length with value 6 to action Add, it should send paramater tekst and value: the input

Comment: Show us your action method so we can help more clearly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what your action looks like but as long as it is accepting your model, you have the value for TEKST in your model..

If you need something different then you're View would need to be different as well, you post a Model from the view, you don't send GET parameters by making a POST

Do you have an action that currently takes TEKST as a parameter?

### **UPDATE**

Ok, looking at your action... you don't need to modify your view, you need to modify your actions, try this this will get you what you want.

Change `YourModelTypeHere` to match your real model type

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(YourModelTypeHere model)
{
    return RedirectToAction("Add", new { tekst = model.tekst });
}

public ActionResult Add(string tekst) 
{
    ViewBag.test = tekst;
    return View();
}
```

You need to modify your view just a tad - remove the parameters from the BeginForm tag

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
```

So the `Create` action will render the `Create` View, then POST back to the `Create` method that has the `[HttpPost]` annotation. Then the value of `TEKST` will be sent as a parameter to the `Add` method as a `RedirectToAction` and render the `Add` view

Comment: @user1408786 great, would you mind marking the answer checked?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure where the "Length=6" is coming from, as I can't see what part of your code would create that URL...

It sounds to me that you're expecting a GET request, but (by default) a form will result in a POST request. Based on your code, I would expect the generated route to be "localhost:4470/Review/Add". Whatever the contents of the form are will be sent as form data.

So in your controller, if your action method looked like this:

```
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("Add")]
public ActionResult AddViaPost(string tekst)
{
    // do something with tekst
}
```

Then you should get the value of the text box posted correctly to your controller.